# Fortify thinks I have an XSS Issue

Tags: boolean, xss, fortify

Fortify is telling me I have a critical issue as an XSS vulnerability.

> Abstract:
>   Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected (Input Validation and Representation, Data flow)
>
> The method DoFoo() in FooController.cs sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line 112, which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

It doesn't like what this method is returning

```
return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
            {
                NameChanged = nameChanged,
                DatabaseUpdated = true,
                HasOpenAccount = contact.HasOpenAccount
            }
     };
```

All three of those values are booleans. The last one (`contact.HasOpenAccount`) is a nullable boolean. That is the one Fortify doesn't like (I think because `contact` is an object passed in from the javascript).

I've messed around with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, and adding it to the `HasOpenAccount` line changes the Fortify issue from critical to medium (poor validation).

I can live with that, but this just doesn't seem like it is really an issue. How can a nullable boolean be vulnerable to malicious attacks? Is this a possibility, or is Fortify being crazy?

**Update:**

I fixed this by changing

`HasOpenAccount = contact.HasOpenAccount`

to

`HasOpenAccount = contact.HasOpenAccount ?? false`

to return false when it is null. This completely fixed the Fortify issue. Apparently it doesn't like nullables? My original question still stands though, is this even a real issue?

Answer (score 0):

If they are all booleans, then simply make a comment that this is a false positive and then flag it as Not An Issue (and/or Suppress it).

Comment: I'm not worried about fixing the issue, just if it really is an issue. It seems like a false positive, but I don't know if I'm overlooking something.